# Unwrap a UInt64 that is wrapped in a voidptr_t

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, jsctypes

In js-ctypes I have received a Windows handle (`voidptr_t`). In some cases a handle is null, so it is returned to me as

```
var ret = ctypes.voidptr_t(ctypes.UInt64('0x0'))
```

I want to unwrap the `voidptr_t` and then do `ctypes.UInt64.compare(ret, ctypes.UInt64('0x0'))`.

Right now I'm doing this funky thing:

```
if (local_hwnd.toString().indexOf('UInt64("0x0")') > -1) {
    console.log('has no handle it is 0 local_hwnd.toString() = ', local_hwnd.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simple null comparisons:

```
ptr.isNull()
```

For actually unwrapping stuff (to `UInt64`):

```
ctypes.cast(ptr, ctypes.uintptr_t).value
```

Comment: Ah! What I was trying was `ctypes.cast(blah, ctypes.UInt64)` and it would always throw `Exception: second argument must be a CType` no clue why. Thanks again man I learned a ton this weekend.\